# How to obtain a rank-5 solution to an optimization problem

Tags: optimization, matrix-rank, constraints

Say I want to determine a matrix solution $A^*$ to the minimization problem $$\min_{A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}} f(A)$$
with the constraint that this solution $A^*$ must have rank $k$, where $k \ll n$. How would one go about this? I'm particularly interested a solution that is immediately applicable in a black-box autodifferentiator (like TensorFlow) rather than theoretical approaches. For example, would it be possible to perform some kind of rank factorization of $A$, like $A = CF$ where $C$ is an $n\times k$ matrix and $F$ is a $k\times n$ matrix, and then optimize over these variables? In my case, the indices of the trivial and nontrivial eigenvalues are known, so would it be as easy as thresholding the eigenvalues? Do there exist assumptions about $A$ which make this type of constraint trivial?

Comment: Since the rank constraint (e.g. $\textrm{rank} A=k$) is nonconvex, this problem is in general "hard" to solve with a provenly-convergent algorithm. While there are heuristic methods used to solve the problem, those methods typically lack convergence guarantees. You may also want to look into "convex relaxation" schemes for rank-constrained optimization, since those methods are pretty fast and sometimes work. If we first solve the problem over $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, then threshold to make the solution rank-$k$, this will not always be a solution to the rank-constrainted problem.

Comment: If $nk$ is small enough, and the stars align, you might be able to solve this to "provable" global optimality using $A = CF$ where $C$ is an $n\times k$ matrix and $F$ is a $k\times n$ matrix, by using a branch and bound global optimizar, such as BARON. I suppose TensorFLow and the ilk only do local optimization, in which case you could give that a go if you could figure out how to get the problem into that framework. BTW, your proposed factorization guarantees the solution will not have a rank  greater than 5, but it could be less than 5. You will have to decide whether that is acceptable.

Comment: Beware that this factorization can introduce many "spurious" saddle points.